# Trying to get the result in single row using sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to display all the employee id's

i need the result like

```
emp_id

10,11,12,13,14,15..,...
```

when tried

> `SELECT LISTAGG(emp_id, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY emp_id) AS ID FROM employees GROUP BY emp_id;`

I'm getting error

> `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`

where is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Use `LISTAGG` function. Refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) for more in detail. Try like this,

```
SELECT listagg(emp_id,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY emp_id) t 
FROM   employees;
```

Answer (score 0):

For SQL try

```
 SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(emp_id) as emp_id FROM employees;
```

Working demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90dd2/1

For Oracle

```
SELECT LISTAGG(emp_id,',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY emp_id) as emp_id 
FROM   employees;
```

demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/af004/9

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT CONCAT(emp_id,',') FROM employees;
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
 declare @empid nvarchar(500)=''
    select @empid=@empid+Emp_id + ',' from tblemployee
    select substring(@empid,0,len(@empid)-1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(emp_id) as emp_id FROM employees;
```